# Problema con INTERRUPT al utilizar multiswitch con arduino

Tags: arduino

Quería hacer una consulta acerca de los INTERRUPT. Tengo un multiswitch y quiero leer las señales a través de Arduino, son 9 señales, una de arranque y las demás de control.

Pero tengo un problema , las señales se leen perfectamente, también se guardan en una matriz pero **cuando llega la hora de jugar con esa matriz el programa no responde**. He probado que a la hora de utilizar los valores de la matriz estos meterlos dentro de la función `noInterrupt()` y cuando finalice `interrupt()` pero me sigue pasando exactamente lo mismo.

Me gustaría saber si alguien le ha sucedido algo parecido o tiene idea y me pueda dar una solución con el fin de resolverlo.

Adjunto el código completo y seguidamente lo describo por fases para un mayor entendimiento.

```
#define Interrupcion 0 // INTERRUPT 0 = DIGITAL PIN 3 - use the interrupt number in attachInterrupt,.....pines 2 y/ó 3 en UNO.
#define ch7 3 // INTERRUPT 0 = DIGITAL PIN 3 - use the PIN number in digitalRead # changed to pin 3 for micro


volatile int pulso = 1500; // volatile, we set this in the Interrupt and read it in loop so it must be declared volatile
volatile unsigned long inicio_flanco = 0; // set in the interrupt
volatile unsigned long valor_inicio_flanco = 0; // set in the interrupt
volatile boolean nuevo_pulso = false; // set in the interrupt and read in the loop

unsigned long dead_time;
unsigned long current_time;

char buffer[80] = "";

int Multi_Switch[50]; //tamaño de la matriz para albergar los 9 valores
int switch_num = 0; // variable para indicar el switch de los 8 posibles

int valor_pulso = 1000; // variable Xpara el valor del pulso a leer, inicializado a 1000

void setup()
{
// should only have to see 8 of these... 9th should be sync signal
Multi_Switch[0] = 1500;// inicializa en el valor central de cada interruptor 
Multi_Switch[1] = 1500;
Multi_Switch[2] = 1500;
Multi_Switch[3] = 1500;
Multi_Switch[4] = 1500;
Multi_Switch[5] = 1500;
Multi_Switch[6] = 1500;
Multi_Switch[7] = 1500;
Multi_Switch[8] = 1500;

// tell the Arduino we want the function calcReceiver to be called whenever INT0 (digital pin 3) changes from HIGH to LOW or LOW to HIGH
// catching these changes will allow us to calculate how long the input pulse is
attachInterrupt(Interrupcion,calcReceiver,CHANGE);

//we will be sending a ton of data
Serial.begin(57600);//57600

dead_time = millis();

Serial.println("system ready");
}

void loop()
{

if(nuevo_pulso == true)
    {
    //copy to our non volatile var
    valor_pulso = pulso; // pulso es el valor volatil. valor_pulso es el valor a utilizar
        if (switch_num < 50)
        {
        Multi_Switch[switch_num] = valor_pulso;
        }
    switch_num++;
    
    nuevo_pulso = false;
    } // end nuevo_pulso

sprintf(buffer ,"valor_pulso %d , counter %d", valor_pulso, switch_num);
Serial.println(buffer);

//servo channel orientation normal
if (valor_pulso < 1000)
  {
  sprintf(buffer ,"valor_pulso < 1000 %d %d this is sync signal", valor_pulso, switch_num);
  Serial.println(buffer);
  switch_num = 0;
  }

//servo channel orientation reversed
if (valor_pulso > 2000)
  {
  sprintf(buffer ,"valor_pulso > 2000 %d %d this is reversed sync signal", valor_pulso, switch_num);
  Serial.println(buffer);
  switch_num = 0;
  }

// Failsafe
current_time = millis();

//it has been 3 seconds since we got a servo pulse...
if ((current_time - dead_time ) > 3000)
  {
  Serial.println("receiver lost signal");
  //change Multi_Switch[0]..Multi_Switch[7] to failsafe values
  }

// put your code here to run through values stored in Multi_Switch[0]...Multi_Switch[7] to position switches/lights/horns/servos accordingly

delay(10); // delay in between reads for stability

// other processing ... 
} //end of void loop()


void calcReceiver()
{
// if the pin is high, its the start of an interrupt
if(digitalRead(ch7) == HIGH)
      { 
      // get the time using micros - when our code gets really busy this will become inaccurate, but for the current application its easy to understand and works very well
      valor_inicio_flanco = inicio_flanco;
      inicio_flanco = micros();
      }
else
{
// if the pin is low, its the falling edge of the pulse so now we can calculate the pulse duration by subtracting the 
// start time inicio_flanco from the current time returned by micros()
if(inicio_flanco && (nuevo_pulso == false))
      {
      pulso = (int)(micros() - inicio_flanco);
      inicio_flanco = 0;
      
      // tell loop we have a new signal on the CHANNEL channel
      // we will not update pulso until loop sets
      // nuevo_pulso back to false
      nuevo_pulso = true;
      
      //reset our dead-man's switch
      dead_time = millis();
      }
}
} //end of void calcReceiver()
```

Ahora lo explicaré paso por paso.

Esta linea de código es la que se encarga de llamar a la función `calReceiver` cada vez que por la entrada **cambia el voltaje**, es decir cada **interrupcion.**

```
attachInterrupt(Interrupcion,calcReceiver,CHANGE);
```

Cuando esto sucede se llama a `calcReceiver.`

```
void calcReceiver()
{
// si la entrada va a alto,es el inicio de una interrupcion
if(digitalRead(ch7) == HIGH)
      { 
     // mide el tiempo en microsegundos - when our code gets really busy this will become inaccurate, but for the current application its easy to understand and works very well
      valor_inicio_flanco = inicio_flanco;
      inicio_flanco = micros();
      }
else
{
//// si la entrada va a bajo, el pulso ha terminado y es el momento de calcular su duracion restando el tiempo de inicio menos el tiempo final devuelto por la funcion micros()
// if the pin is low, its the falling edge of the pulse so now we can calculate the pulse duration by subtracting the 
// start time inicio_flanco from the current time returned by micros()
if(inicio_flanco && (nuevo_pulso == false))
      {
      pulso = (int)(micros() - inicio_flanco);
      inicio_flanco = 0;

      // tell loop we have a new signal on the CHANNEL channel
      // we will not update pulso until loop sets
      // nuevo_pulso back to false
      nuevo_pulso = true;

      //reset our dead-man's switch
      dead_time = millis();
      }
}
```

Cuando acaba entra en loop de nuevo y **en esta parte es cuando se carga la matriz con los valores que envía la señal de radio.**

```
if(nuevo_pulso == true)
    {
// si detecta un pulso, guarda el valor en la matriz, si no, sigue el loop
    //copy to our non volatile var
    valor_pulso = pulso; // pulso es el valor volatil. valor_pulso es el valor a utilizar
        if (switch_num < 50)
        {
        Multi_Switch[switch_num] = valor_pulso;
        }
    switch_num++;
     // cambiar el boleano a falso al terminar
  // con pulso, mientras sea verdadero, calcInput no actualizara el pulso
    nuevo_pulso = false;
    } // end nuevo_pulso
```

**Todo el código restante solo sirve para mostrar informacioón y saber cuando empieza de nuevo el arranque** es decir cuando poner la matriz a 0 de nuevo.

*El problema como anteriormente he dicho es que la matriz se carga con los valores pero a la hora de mostrarlos y utilizar esos valores en condiciones resulta imposible.*

Gracias a las personas que colaboran y se ayudan sin intereses. :)

Comment: por curiosidad ¿ basaste tu codigo en esto ? http://subcommittee.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-32808.html

Comment: Si! Esta basado en ese codigo!! Pero no hay forma de utilizar los valores de la matriz, solo imprime!